# Write a CSV without delimiters in Python

Tags: python, list, csv, delimiter

I'm having a problem...

I have a list of a number of websites, like this example.

```
[u'www.rosenzweigco.com', u'www.investopedia.com', u'www.bk.mufg.jp']
```

However, when I want to have a CSV file, I'm getting this:

```
w,w,w,.,r,o,s,e,n,z,w,e,i,g,c,o,.,c,o,m,
w,w,w,.,i,n,v,e,s,t,o,p,e,d,i,a,.,c,o,m,
```

My code is the following (I need no space instead of the commas):

```
def writeCsvFile(fname,data):
mycsv = csv.writer(open(fname, 'wb'), delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
for row in data:
    mycsv.writerow(row)
```

Tks!!

Answer (score 1):

`.writerow` takes an iterable and writes each item in the iterable as a column in your csv.  It looks like you are passing a single string as `row`.  In this case, you'd want:

```
for website in data:
    mycsv.writerow([website])
```

However, I'm guessing this isn't *quite* what you want since there is no need for `csv` if you just want to write one item per line.  The problem is probably in how you are specifying `data` to the `writeCsvFile` function.  Perhaps you want the following:

```
data = [[u'www.rosenzweigco.com', u'www.investopedia.com', u'www.bk.mufg.jp']]
```

Notice that now `data` is a list of lists.  So when you iterate over it (`for row in data`), you'll actually get a row (`list`) instead of just a single string.

Answer (score 0):

The first idea struck me is the same as mgilson's answer.
Also, if you are using python 3 , you need to open file with 'w' parameter, without binary mode unlike the python 2.7

Python 3.5

```
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

Python 2.7

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```