# Write text file to specific column in CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, csv

I have a text file and I want to write it's content to a specific column in CSV file.
here is my code

```
import csv
f1 = open ("input.txt","r") # open input file for reading
f = f1.read()

with open('output.csv','w') as csvfile: # input csv file
            a = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')

              # edit the 8th column
            a.writerow(str(f))
f1.close()
```

The input.txt:
    THIS IS FILE ONE

my problem is it writes each letter in a row not the whole sentence and how can I assign to a specific column like `row[0]` to have the content.

```
output.csv(r means row)
r1 r2 r3 r4     r5 r6  r7  r8  r9  r10  r11  r12  r13
T  H   I  S     I  S   F    I  L   E     O    N    E
```

Comment: Please show a sample of the content of `input.txt` and what you want `out.csv` to look like.

Comment: I edited the question and include an example.

Comment: is it row or column?

Comment: Sorry you are correct , it's columns. . That because I changed writerow to writerows and it put each letter in row...But I  want the only row [0]

Comment: @YousraGad, do you by any chance mean `T,H,I,S, ,I,S, ,F,I,L,E, ,O,N,E`? Because you are using a comma as a delimiter.

Comment: yes @Abdou , even when I remove delimiter.. Still the problem remain

Comment: @YousraGad I'm still not sure what you want your desired output to be. Do you want one letter per row?

Comment: No I want (THIS IS FILE ONE) in row [0] only

Answer (score 0):

I find [this question related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618674/write-a-csv-without-delimiters-in-python)  to what I want. I edited my code and It works perfect:

```
import csv
row = []
f1 = open ("input.txt","r") # open input file for reading
file = f1.read()
row.append(file)

with open('output.csv','w', newline='') as csvfile: # input csv file
            a = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            for i in row:

                     a.writerow([i])
f1.close()
```